# Java Optionals: not null and method OR default value

Tags: java

How can I make that shorter/more elegant with an Optional??

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = getMyTime ();   // returns ZonedDateTime or null
String zdtstr = "";
if (zdt != null)
{
    zdtstr = zdt.format (myformatter);
}
else
{
    zdtstr = "???";
}
```

I tried Optional.isPresentorElse but it does not return a result (String I need in my sample).

Comment: Try with `map` and `orElse`

Comment: `zdtstr = (zdt == null) ? "???" : zdt.format(myformatter);` ?! (no for for creating an additional instance, couple of method calls, ....)

Comment: Don't really see the point. If your method doesn't return an `Optional` to begin with, might as well just use a ternary operator: `String zdtstr = zdt != null ? zdt.format(myformatter) : "???";`

Comment: I would consider changing `getMyTime` to return an optional. Then you could to `String zdtstr = getMyTime().map(myformatter::format).orElse("???");`

Comment: When null is a legitimate return value of a method, that method should return an `Optional`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use a ternary operator :

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = getMyTime();
String zdtstr = (zdt != null) ? zdt.format(myformatter) : "???";
```

Answer (score 4):

if `getMyTime()` can return null, you can even have this getter to return an `Optional` in the first place.

```
Optional<ZonedDateTime> getMyTime() { 
    return Optional.ofNullable(myTime); 
}
```

As a result, you can use it nicely, in a declarative and null-safe way:

```
getMyTime()
  .map(zdt -> zdt.format(myformatter));
  .orElse("???");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ofNullable` to transfer the `null` into an empty `Optional`, then use `orElse`.

```
String zdtStr = Optional.ofNullable(getMyTime())
 .map(zdt -> zdt.format(myformatter));
 .orElse("???");
```

Comment: This isn't shorter though. Or, only if you cheat and use prejudicial style guide rules, in which case I can make it shorter still by removing all spaces from this, which seems silly.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Not sure what you mean, I consider 3 lines shorter than 5. And I do find it more elegant, but that's always a matter of taste of course.

Comment: For `if`, you MUST use braces, but with lambda functions you don't? Then the problem is the style guide and not that lambdas are somehow shorter than a simple `if`.

Comment: What style guide do you keep referring to? OP was asking a question how to transform his code into an `Optional` construct, I answered it. Not sure how not adding braces around a lambda invalidates that (and, fwiw, I didn't count the braces as lines anyway).

Comment: The one that makes you say 'with `if` it is 5 lines but with `.ofNullable` it is 3. That doesn't make sense unless your style guide dictates that `if` MUST use braces but also says that lambda don't have to, which is inconsistent.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm talking about logical lines, ie pretty much statements.

Comment: See Xiidref's answer which does it in 2, if you go by that metric. If `getMyTime()` is, as the `get` suggests, not expensive, it could do it in 1.

Comment: Im aware of the ternary operator and use it quite often. It's not "my metric", op explicitly asked about "shorter" and "Optional".